# For a selected delivery mode, set delivery cost to zero - Promotion Engine (Hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

I want to create a new custom action to set the delivery cost as zero for cart/order level. Is there any OOTB strategy already include this kind of action. If not, what should be logic of this newly created strategy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB promotion template is available to support your conditions and action.

But you can write custom Condition and Action for the above scenario.
Please follow this trail to implement custom RAO, condition, and Action.

[How to create Custom Condition and Action as per requirement](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2011/en-US/433804dce6a5453d936e13ae2776c2d0.html)